# Сравнение двух json

Tags: python, json

Я новичек в питоне, отсюда и вопрос

Подаю get запрос в api, она возвращает json, после чего данный json парсится.

```
json_data = requests.get("/api/claims/9d7fd5bc")
data = {"": "", "": ""}  
parsed_json = json.loads(json_data.content) 
print data == parsed_json
```

Теперь необходимо полученный json сравнить с эталонным примером.
Эталон сохранен как локально на машине так и в самом проекте.
С помощью чего я могу сравнить их на выходе получить значения которые не прошли проверку? 
Да и реально ли это вообще?

Comment: вы можете превратить оба json в словари и сравнить словари

Comment: Если важны только названия полей/ключей, а не их значения, копайте в сторону jsonschema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если схема json идентична, и нужно выявить только различия значений в одинаковых ключах, то можно сравнить словари, полученные из json:

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
b = {'a':2, 'b':2}

deltas = {i: a[i] for i in a if i in b and a[i] != b[i]}
if len(deltas):
    print ("There are differences!\nJSON 1 | JSON 2")
    for key, value in deltas.items():
        print (key, "->", value, '|',key, "->", b[key])
```

Получим:

```
There are differences!
JSON 1 | JSON 2
a -> 1 | a -> 2
```

Comment: `print (key, "->", value, '|',key, "->", b[key])` -> `print("{} -> {} | {} -> {}".format(key, value, key, b[key]))`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!